# custom jQuery plugin: events not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, events

I'm writing a lightweight jQuery plugin to detect dirty forms but having some trouble with events. As you can see in the following code, the plugin attaches an event listener to 'beforeunload' that tests if a form is dirty and generates a popup is that is the case.

There is also another event listener attached to that form's "submit" that should in theory remove the 'beforeunload' listener for that specific form (i.e. the current form I am submitting should not be tested for dirt, but other forms on the page should be).

I've inserted a bunch of console.log statements to try and debug it but no luck. Thoughts?

```
  // Checks if any forms are dirty if leaving page or submitting another forms
  // Usage:
  // $(document).ready(function(){
  //    $("form.dirty").dirtyforms({
  //      excluded: $('#name, #number'),
  //      message: "please don't leave dirty forms around"
  //    });
  // });


  (function($) {

    ////// private variables //////

    var instances = [];

    ////// general private functions //////

    function _includes(obj, arr) {
        return (arr._indexOf(obj) != -1);
    }

    function _indexOf(obj) {
      if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, fromIndex) {
          if (fromIndex == null) {
            fromIndex = 0;
          } else if (fromIndex < 0) {
            fromIndex = Math.max(0, this.length + fromIndex);
          }
          for (var i = fromIndex, j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (this[i] === obj)
            return i;
          }
          return -1;
        };
      }
    }

    ////// the meat of the matter //////

    // DirtyForm initialization
    var DirtyForm = function(form, options) {

      // unique name for testing purposes
      this.name = "instance_" + instances.length

      this.form = form;

      this.settings = $.extend({
        'excluded'  : [],
        'message'   : 'You will lose all unsaved changes.'
        }, options);

        // remember intial state of form
        this.memorize_current();

        // activate dirty tracking, but disable it if this form is submitted
        this.enable();
        $(this.form).on('submit', $.proxy(this.disable, this));

        // remember all trackable forms
        instances.push(this);
      }

      // DirtyForm methods
      DirtyForm.prototype = {

        memorize_current: function() {
          this.originalForm = this.serializeForm();
        },

        isDirty: function() {
          var currentForm = this.serializeForm();
          console.log("isDirty called...")
          return (currentForm != this.originalForm);
        },

        enable: function() {
          $(window).on('beforeunload', $.proxy(this.beforeUnloadListener, this));
          console.log("enable called on " + this.name)
        },

        disable: function(e) {
          $(window).off('beforeunload', $.proxy(this.beforeUnloadListener, this));
          console.log("disable called on " + this.name)
        },

        disableAll: function() {
          $.each(instances, function(index, instance) {
            $.proxy(instance.disable, instance)
          });
        },

        beforeUnloadListener: function(e) {
          console.log("beforeUnloadListener called on " + this.name)
          console.log("... and it is " + this.isDirty())
          if (this.isDirty()) {
            e.returnValue = this.settings.message;
            return this.settings.message;
          }
        },

        setExcludedFields: function(excluded) {
          this.settings.excluded = excluded;
          this.memorize_current();
          this.enable();
        },

        serializeForm: function() {
          var blacklist = this.settings.excludes
          var filtered = [];
          var form_elements = $(this.form).children();

          // if element is not in the excluded list
          // then let's add it to the list of filtered form elements
          if(blacklist) {
            $.each(form_elements, function(index, element) {
              if(!_includes(element, blacklist)) {
                filtered.push(element);
              }
            });
            return $(filtered).serialize(); 
          } else {
            return $(this.form).serialize();
          } 
        }
      };

      ////// the jquery plugin part //////

      $.fn.dirtyForms = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
          new DirtyForm(this, options);
        });
      };

    })(jQuery);
```

[EDIT]

I ended up fixing this by using jQuery's .on() new namespace feature to identify the handler. The problem was that I was passing new anonymous functions as the handler argument to .off(). Thanks @FelixKling for your solution!

```
    this.id = instances.length

    [...]

    enable: function () {
        $(window).on('beforeunload.' + this.id, $.proxy(this.beforeUnloadListener, this));
    },

    disable: function () {
        $(window).off('beforeunload.' + this.id);
    },
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, can you have a live demo on your custom plugin. I'm really appreciated the solution you posted,

Comment: Sure @Roy, I just uploaded a demo to http://niftysauce.com/demo/dirtyforms/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are calling `$.proxy()` it returns a **new** function. Thus,

```
$(window).off('beforeunload', $.proxy(this.beforeUnloadListener, this));
```

won't have any effect, since you are trying to unbind a function which was not bound.

You have to store a reference to the function created with `$.proxy`, so that you can unbind it later:

```
enable: function() {
    this.beforeUnloadListener = $.proxy(DirtyForm.prototype.beforeUnloadListener, this);
    $(window).on('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadListener);
    console.log("enable called on " + this.name)
},

disable: function(e) {
    $(window).off('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadListener);
    console.log("disable called on " + this.name)
},
```

Comment: I beat you to the solution by about 5 minutes but I'm giving you the point since that was indeed the right answer :D I ended up with slightly different code but addressed the problem you mentioned. See my edit in the question.